# OAuth Callback Session

Tags: servlets, twitter, callback, oauth

I'm having a problem figuring out to maintain the same session after I get the oauth callback in a servlet.  Since th callback come from Twitter and not the clients browser, I get a different session.

Can someone help??

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing about servlets, I offer three pieces of generic advice.

1 - start a new session when you get the OAuth callback.
2 - store a Session Id in a cookie and retrieve later
3 - the OAuth token begins with nnnnnn-XXXXX where nnn is the users twitter Id.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can also provide additional querystring parameters in the callback url and they will be provided when the user returns from authenticating.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this [issue](https://github.com/aiten/grails-oauth-scribe/issues/3#issuecomment-5279474) in my development environment, where my callback URL was different from the URL I was accessing my local application from.

So, if the callback URL is http://myapp.apps.com, you should start accessing your application via the same URL (configured via /etc/hosts).

Some further details are available in this [post](http://www.every108minutes.com/2013/06/local-testing-social-signin.html).